# Get value from associative array with string

Tags: javascript

I have a json response I'm getting from a server with different response structures.

One uses another value "data" to store a link:

[image]

and the other doesn't (with "image" being the link):

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way I can get the "data.link" from the associative array with a reusable method, with linkVariableName being the key of the associative array.

```
function addLink(responseText, successVariableName, isError, linkVariableName)
{
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(responseText);

    var state;
    if (isError)
        state = !jsonResponse[successVariableName];
    else
        state = jsonResponse[successVariableName];

    if (state) {
        var link = jsonResponse[linkVariableName];
        insertAtCursor(textArea, '[img]' + link + '[/img]\r\n');
    } else
        console.log('Error: ' + responseText);
}
```

so I can use either

```
addLink(response.responseText, 'success', false, 'data.link');
```

or

```
addLink(response.responseText, 'error', true, 'image');
```

Comment: How do you determine which parameters to the pass to the function?

Comment: Note: JavaScript does not have associative arrays.

Comment: @gcampbell I'm use to associating json with associative arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, as explained here: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/218196)

However, IMO the function tries to do too much. Why does it need to parse the JSON and extract the value? You could just pass the value directly to it:

```
function addLink(link) {
  insertAtCursor(textArea, '[img]' + link + '[/img]\r\n');
}
```

And move the other logic to where you handle the response:

```
var isError = ...;
var response = JSON.parse(responseText);

if (isError && !response.error) {
  addLink(response.image);
} else if(!isError && response.success) {
  addLink(response.data.link);
} else {
  console.log('Error: ' + responseText);
}
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CxeKSpZ.gif

It's quite cluttered as it is.. I figured putting everything in that method would make it a little more clear.

Thank you for your solution.